# Gradle build spring boot properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Spring Boot Gradle project with yml configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username:
    password:
    url:
```

When I run `./gradlew clean build` Gradle runs all my tests. 
How can I pass datasource parameters using command-line?

I tried something like `./gradlew clean build -Dspring.datasource.url...` but it doesn't work. 
I Also tried `./gradlew clean build -Pspring.datasource.url`, created a variable inside gradle.build and then set systemProperty, but it also doesn't work.

Does anyone have an easy solution?

Comment: what is the purpose? Usually you would pass this information in the moment you run this application, not on the build action...

Comment: I need to check whether all tests are passed after git push. CI does this using gradle build task.